# how to stack layers of div using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to achieve the following:
[layered div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtEBP.png)

rows are working, but I can't put the top layer div (the one with the class map) in the right place, it always pushes some of the rows to the side. how can I achieve the desired result using bootstrap?

```css
/*  my css: (index.css) */
.container-full {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 90%;
   margin-bottom: 100px;
 }

.blue-row{
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(#4b7fe4, #99B4E8)
}
.grey-row{
    background-color: #e3e3e3;   
}

.darkgrey-row{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #bebebe;   
}

.map{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:9999;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-full" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="row blue-row">
asas     
</div>
<div class="row grey-row">
    <div class="map"> <!-- top layer div -->
        content          
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row darkgrey-row">asasas</div>
```

Comment: do you want top layer div to the center of whole screen or just center to gray row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.container-full {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 90%;
   margin-bottom: 100px;
  position:relative;
 }

.blue-row{
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(#4b7fe4, #99B4E8)
}
.grey-row{
    background-color: #e3e3e3;   
}

.darkgrey-row{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #bebebe;   
}

.map{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    background:red;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    z-index:9999;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-full" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="row blue-row">
asas     
</div>
<div class="row grey-row">
    <div class="map"> <!-- top layer div -->
        content          
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row darkgrey-row">asasas</div>
```

Comment: if you plan to use bootstrap, you could consider using a modal http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#static-example

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

If you want that top level div stay where it is, you can make `.map > position:absolute`

```css
.container-full {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 90%;
   margin-bottom: 100px;
 }

.blue-row{
    height: 200px;
    background: linear-gradient(#4b7fe4, #99B4E8)
}
.grey-row{
    background-color: #e3e3e3;   
    height:150px;
}

.darkgrey-row{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #bebebe;   
}

.map{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    z-index:9999;
    background:red;
    left:-50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container container-full" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="row blue-row">
asas     
</div>
<div class="row grey-row">
    <div class="map">
      content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row darkgrey-row">asasas</div>
</div>
```